# Traversing table rows until a known element using PHP Simple HTML Dom parser

Tags: php, xml, simple-html-dom

Ok im trying to build an xml feed from this HTML table using **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**.

```
<table>
<tr><td colspan="5"><strong>Saturday October 15 2011</strong></td></tr>

<tr><td>Team 1</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 7</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 2</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 12</td>    <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 3</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 8</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 4</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 10</td>    <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 5</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 11</td>    <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="5"><strong>Monday October 17 2011</strong></td></tr>

<tr><td>Team 6</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 9</td> <td>7:45 pm</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="5"><strong>Saturday October 22 2011</strong></td></tr>

<tr><td>Team 7</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 12</td>    <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 1</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 2</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 8</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 4</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 3</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 6</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 9</td>     <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 5</td> <td>3:00 pm</td></td></tr>
<tr><td>Team 10</td>        <td>vs</td>     <td>Team 11</td>    <td>3:00 pm</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I am aiming to do is extract the Date and then the following rows up until the next date. so that I can build an XML node as such for each of the dates.

```
<matchday date="Saturday October 15 2011">
    <fixture>
        <hometeam>Team 1</hometeam>
        <awayteam>Team 7</awayteam>
        <kickoff>3:00 pm</kickoff>
    </fixture>
    <fixture>
        <hometeam>Team 2</hometeam>
        <awayteam>Team 12</awayteam>
        <kickoff>3:00 pm</kickoff>
    </fixture>
</matchday>
```

I have at present each of the dates from the html and built their respective xml nodes

```
$dateNodes = $html->find('table tr td[colspan="5"] strong');

foreach($dateNodes as $date){
    echo '<matchday day="'.trim($date->innertext).'">';
    // FIXTURES

    // END FIXTURES
    echo '</matchday>';
}
```

How would i go about getting the team names etc for each fixture up until the next matchday date?

Comment: You did not accept an answer yet. Can you please clarify what you are looking for in an answer and why the given answers do not satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead if [SimpleHtmlDom (which I believe is a craptaculous library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662), you can use an [XSLT transformation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/XSLT) and [PHP's native XSLT processor](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <matchdays>
      <xsl:for-each select="table/tr[td[@colspan=5]]">
        <matchday>
          <xsl:attribute name="date">
            <xsl:value-of select="td/strong"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::tr[
            not(td[@colspan]) and 
            preceding-sibling::tr[td[@colspan]][1] = current()
          ]">
            <fixture>
              <hometeam><xsl:value-of select="td[1]"/></hometeam>
              <awayteam><xsl:value-of select="td[3]"/></awayteam>
              <kickoff><xsl:value-of select="td[4]"/></kickoff>
            </fixture>
          </xsl:for-each>                   
        </matchday>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </matchdays>
  </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then just use the code given in the example at http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php to transform your HTML to the XML:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('YourSourceFile.xml');
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('YourStyleSheet.xsl');
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xml);
```

[Demo at Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/K2J4lG)

---

In addition to using XSLT, you can also do it with PHP's native DOM extension:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->loadHtmlFile('YourHtmlFile.xml');
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);   
$new = new DOMDocument('1,0', 'utf-8');
$new->appendChild($new->createElement('matchdays'));
foreach ($xp->query('//table/tr/td[@colspan=5]/strong') as $gameDate) {
    $matchDay = $new->createElement('matchday');
    $matchDay->setAttribute('date', $gameDate->nodeValue);
    foreach ($xp->query(
        sprintf(
            '//tr[
                not(td[@colspan]) and
                preceding-sibling::tr[td[@colspan]][1]/td/strong/text() = "%s"
            ]',
            $gameDate->nodeValue
        )
    ) as $gameData) {
        $tds = $gameData->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $fixture = $matchDay->appendChild($new->createElement('fixture'));
        $fixture->appendChild($new->createElement(
            'hometeam', $tds->item(0)->nodeValue)
        );
        $fixture->appendChild($new->createElement(
            'awayteam', $tds->item(2)->nodeValue)
        );
        $fixture->appendChild($new->createElement(
            'kickoff', $tds->item(3)->nodeValue)
        );
    }
    $new->documentElement->appendChild($matchDay);
}
$new->formatOutput = true;
echo $new->saveXML();
```

[Demo at Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YpxVTH)

Comment: Is it possible to load in an external url into the $xml->loadHtmlFile('YourHtmlFile.xml'); ie if i wanted to parse another website to retrieve its data

Comment: @ChrisMJ yes. please refer to the [manual for DOM for details](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/book.dom.php)